# how to use assert in selenium python to check my page load time is less than 5 sec?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
start2 = datetime.datetime.now()

button8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Last Month')]").click()

timeout = time.time() + 60 * 2
while len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("path[class='area areaChart']")) != 16:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if time.time() > timeout:
         break
print('Last month option selected')
elapsed2 = datetime.datetime.now()
x = elapsed2 - start2
print(x)
#print("Elapsed Time2 = {0}".format(elapsed2 - start2))
#if x <= 5:
assert (x <= 5),"VM4 is working good!"
```

Comment: Note that Selenium is not a reliable performance testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for [WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) function, if page loading time will be exceeded - Selenium will throw an error automatically.

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
```

You can also use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of your construction:

```
wait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("path[class='area areaChart']")) != 16)
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)